# AngularJS use expression calculation done in html again

Tags: angularjs

I want to know if there is any way in AngularJS, where I can reuse the angular expression calculation done on HTML somewhere else on the same HTML. For example, if I calculate:

```
{{object.a * (object.b + (object.c / object.d))}}
```

at one location and I want to use the same value to calculate something else say:

```
{{(object.a * (object.b + (object.c / object.d))) / 100}}
```

such that I do not write the whole expression already there again.
One thing I want to mention here is I do not want to use controller in this condition or directive.
Thanks.

Comment: Don't want to use a controller? Where is `object` coming from then?

Comment: @m59 - Hi, the object is coming from the controller but I want to see if I can assign the expression calculated on the HTML and use it somewhere else on the same HTML. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save result of the expression in new variable

```
{{ result = ( object.a * (object.b + (object.c / object.d)) ) }}
```

and use it later

```
{{result}}
```

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I am looking for.